# The content part showing extra white spacing on scroll

Tags: html, css

```css
header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 57px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    float: left;
    right: 0;
}
article {
    /*position: fixed;*/
    width: 100%;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    float: left;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 57px;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    }
footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
    right: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
        </header>
        <article>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p><p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>testing...........</p>
            <p>working...?</p>
            <p>working...?</p>
            <p>working...?</p>
            <p>working...?</p>
            <p>working...?</p>
            <p>working...?</p>
            <p>working...?</p>
            <p>working...?</p>
            <p>working...?</p>
            <p>working...?</p>
            <p>working...?</p>
            <p>working...?</p>
        </article>
        <footer>
        </footer>
```

In this above code i'm tried to fix the top and header part always on their respective position and the content part can be scrolled according to it's length.

1. The problem i'm facing is that when the scroll bar is moving upward there is a white space is showing.i don't know how to handle that,some times which is displayed on bottom too
2. One another problem i'm facing is the extra padding on content part.I'm given the property value `right:0` to article.but it,s still showing some padding.

how can i fix this two problems?

Answer (score 1):

In most major browsers, the default body margin is 8px on all sides. It is defined in pixels by the user-agent-stylesheet your browser provides.

You have to just add css for body:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;      
}
```

But if you have a large project and want to be more complete, use [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). It resets a lot of default values to be consistent across browsers.

Comment: thanks bro...that solved the second problem,and your answer is a **great knowledge** to me. tnx again

Comment: i want to fix the first problem too

Answer (score 0):

at first you have to make normalize HTML element by margin and padding using like this

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```